# jquery click only affect specified child

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-animate

I try to create a menu with multiple sub-menus. My idea was to use *divs* for each submenu with height: 0px and borders, so it appears as a line (only on hover, mimicking kind of the known 'this is a clickable link'). If you press it, it expands using jQuery's animate and revealing the submenu.

**Issue 1:** The jQuery code always animates *every* div with class 'submenu'. I tried using something like this to only affect children

```
if ($(this, '.submenu')
```

or nth-child(2), children selector or 'div', but nothing seems to work. The jsfiddle explains the issue.

**Issue 2:** The submenu collapses after pressing a sublink, but I'd like it not to do that. Could the jQuery event only be triggered if clicked on the parent?

**Issue 3:** If clicked on a new menu point, the animation of a new submenu should be triggered and the old one should collapse at the same time.

**CSS**

```
.nav {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
}
.nav .submenu {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    height: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nav .active {
    color: red;
}
.nav .active + .submenu {
    border-color: black;
}
a:hover {
    color: blue !important;
}
a:hover + .submenu {
  border-color: black !important;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="menu">
        <a class="">Menu1</a>
        <div class="submenu">
            <li><a>Submenu1</a></li>
            <li><a>Submenu2</a></li>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <a class="">Menu2</a>
        <div class="submenu">
            <li><a>Submenu1</a></li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav .menu a').click(function(){
            $('a').removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav .menu a').click(function () {
        if ($('.submenu').css('height') == '0px') {
            $('.submenu').animate({height:100}, 1000);
            $('.submenu').css("border-color","black");
        } else {
            $('a').removeClass("active");
            $('.submenu').animate({height:0}, 1000,function(){
                $('.submenu').css("border-color","transparent");    
            });
        }
    });
});
```

[here's the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SlightEngineering/7oy7kyLf/2/)

Help would be much appreciated! I have learned so many things using this website, but JavaScript is even too hard to even google correctly ;)

Comment: is this what you want `? https://jsfiddle.net/w4c6x6fh/

Comment: You have it backwards. `$(this, '.submenu')` should be `$('.submenu', this)` or `$(this).find('.submenu')`

Comment: Please ask just *one* question at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
$('.menu a').on('click',function(){

    //Because of the ordering of your html, you should just use the .next() 
    //to 
    //get the surrounding div that holds  your submenu
    var subMenu = $(this).next();
    //Then go through the children of this list and show, hide, or do 
     //whatever you want to the elements
     $(submenu).childern().each(functon(){
             //style each div accordingly 

       });


 });
```

If you wanted to just show the menu, you wouldn't need to get the children, just the .next() from the clicked a tag